# center-block using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to center the content of form.

```
<div class="login-container">
 <div class="center-block">
    <form action="/joinChart" method="get">
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="enter your name">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

in style.css (for center-block)

```
.center-block {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
 }

.element {
   . center-block();
}
```

and for login-container:

```
  .login-container {
position: absolute;
width: calc(100% - 20px);
max-width: 800px;
height: 500px;
border-radius: 10px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
overflow: hidden;
}
```

But I cant do it.

Comment: Have you added `bootstrap-4` tag because you're using Bootstrap 4? In the code you're showing, you're not using it at all.

Comment: No, I add /webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.    I specified tag "Bootstrap 4" because of this site does not allow me to specify simple tag "Bootstrap"

Comment: There is no such thing as `bootstrap`. It's one of the four versions. They're different enough so that an answer for one version doesn't usually work for another version. Considering the body of your question and the answer you selected as correct, there's nothing in them that has to do with Bootstrap 4, although Bootstrap 4 does have utility classes that could be used to answer your question. So I'll just remove the tag.

Comment: Replacing `center-block` with `text-center` class and placing `d-flex justify-content-center` classes on your `<form>` would be the Bootstrap 4 way of doing it, btw.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/htkornd4/). Vertical and horizontal centering without any extra CSS (Bootstrap 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with e.g. Flexbox:

https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#align-items

```css
.center-block {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-container {
background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="center-block">
    <form action="/joinChart" method="get">
      <input name="username" id="username" type="text"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="enter your name">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this website as it contains multiple methods you could do to center your form div:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-things-with-style-in-css-dc87b7542689/

Answer (score -1):

Different browsers require different CSS. If you're using Google Chrome, or Opera, or Microsoft Edge, then your code should be working. However, if you're using Internet Explorer, then in your `.center-block` CSS selector, you should also include `text-align : center;` after the margins.